# I have a list of lists how do i classify based on language?

Tags: python, sorting

```
I have three lists:
    id = [1,3,4]
    text = ["hello","hola","salut"]
    date = ["20-12-2020","21-04-2018","15-04-2016"]

#I then combined it all in one list:
    new_list = zip(id, text, date)

#which looks like [(1,"hello","20-12-2020"),(3,"hola","21-04-2018"),(4,"salut","15-04-2016")

I want to delete the whole list if it is not in english, do to this i installed lang id and am using lang id.classify

I ran a loop on only the text and its working but am unsure how to delete the whole value such as: (3,"hola","21-04-2018") as hola is not in english.
```

I am trying to achieve a new list which only has those lists in it that is only english. I want to further write the output list in a xml file.
To do that I have made a sample xml file and am using the date as a parent key as the date can be same for multiple texts.

Comment: if new_list[1][1] is engilsh then new_list.pop(1). Here 1 can be refered as index of each element

Comment: but how do i make it a loop? My actual list has 1000s of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple for loop

```
new_list = [(1,"hello","20-12-2020"),(3,"hola","21-04-2018"),(4,"salut","15-04-2016")]

for x in new_list:
    # condition to check if word or sentence is english
    if not isEnglishWord(x[1]):
        new_list.pop(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how lang `id.classify` works or what parameters it takes in but something like this should work:

```
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    if id.classify(new_list[i][1]) != 'english':
        new_list.pop[i]
```

In this case, I'm assuming id.classify takes in a str and outputs which language the word belongs (as a str).

I'm also using the range list method to iterate so we don't end up changing the list as we are iterating over it.